# HTACCESS 500 internal server error website gone down

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a minor change in my .htaccess file and I'm now receiving a 500 internal server error. I changed it back to how it was before the error but, the error is still there.

Here is the file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error-page.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^dsa-office /(.*)/ dsa_office.php?location=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /$1.php?location=$2 [L]
```

I edit one of the last 3 lines. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule looks suspicious:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dsa-office /(.*)/ dsa_office.php?location=$1
```

It has space in the matching patter between `^dsa-office` and `/(.*)/`

Change this rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dsa-office/(.*?)/?$ dsa_office.php?location=$1 [L,QSA]
```